# Automate animation of raster images in a directory with timestamps

Tags: qgis, animation

I have raster files in a directory, each of which 15 minutes interval. I want to animate it via automation process with timestamps over it. I am able to do it by manually but I want to automate the process.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how you do it manually, as a starting point for the automisation.

Comment: First I load the images manually.Then I activate the time manager plugin give the proper stating and ending date and start the animation.